# Importing Virtual field in a geopackage

Tags: qgis-3, geopackage, virtual-field

I have defined a virtual field to generate additional information in dependence of another attribute. Now I want to import the shape in a geopackage. I want to have the virtual field in the geopackage too. Is it possible?

Comment: With apologies for my entire ignorance, could you add some information (such as a link to) about geopag/geopac software? (as  I couldn't find any of these keywords in this forum).

Comment: Hi Kazuhito,  sorry for my bath information. I mean Geopackage format in QGis 3, thaks a lot vor your time

Comment: Aah, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by saving the layer style to the GeoPackage. Virtual fields are part of the style definition.

Answer (score 1):

GeoPackage doesn't really represent the concept of a virtual field. So I think you'll need to either:

- materialize the derived field, or
- generate the base data, then create a view over the top of the base data with the virtual field added.

Comment: Thanks, I have it done in the same form. I am looking for attributes that are defined in relation to others. But I think with this solution is also posible.